# Extract data from a site using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am making a program that will extract the data from http://www.gujarat.ngosindia.com/

I wrote the following code :

```
def split_line(text):

    words = text.split()
    i = 0
    details = ''
    while ((words[i] !='Contact')) and (i<len(words)):
        i=i+1
        if(words[i] == 'Contact:'):
            break
    while ((words[i] !='Purpose')) and (i<len(words)):
        if (words[i] == 'Purpose:'):
            break
        details = details+words[i]+' '
        i=i+1
    print(details)

def get_ngo_detail(ngo_url):
        html=urlopen(ngo_url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'border3'})
        td = soup.find('td', {'class': 'border'})
        split_line(td.text)

def get_ngo_names(gujrat_url):
    html = urlopen(gujrat_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for link in soup.findAll('div',{'id':'mainbox'}):
        for text in link.find_all('a'):
            print(text.get_text())
            ngo_link = 'http://www.gujarat.ngosindia.com/'+text.get('href')
            get_ngo_detail(ngo_link)
            #NGO_name = text2.get_text())

a = get_ngo_names(BASE_URL)

print a
```

But when i run this script i only get the name of NGOs and contact person.
I want Email, telephone number, website, purpose and contact person.

Comment: as a first step towards finding a solution, try throwing in a couple of print() to verify that the data is correct/what you expect in all instances...

Comment: Or use pdb to step into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `split_line` could be improved. Imagine you have this text:

```
s = """Add: 3rd Floor Khemha House
Drive in Road, Opp Drive in Cinema
Ahmedabad - 380 054
Gujarat
Tel: 91-79-7457611 , 79-7450378
Email: a.mitra1@lse.ac.uk
Website: http://www.aavishkaar.org
Contact: Angha Mitra
Purpose: Economics and Finance, Micro-enterprises
Aim/Objective/Mission: To provide timely financing, management support and professional expertise ..."""
```

Now we can turn this into lines using `s.split("\n")` (split on each new line), giving a list where each item is a line:

```
lines = s.split("\n")
lines == ['Add: 3rd Floor Khemha House', 
          'Drive in Road, Opp Drive in Cinema', 
          ...]
```

We can define a list of the elements we want to extract, and a dictionary to hold the results:

```
targets = ["Contact", "Purpose", "Email"]
results = {}
```

And work through each line, capturing the information we want:

```
for line in lines:
    l = line.split(":")
    if l[0] in targets:
        results[l[0]] = l[1]
```

This gives me:

```
results == {'Contact': ' Angha Mitra', 
            'Purpose': ' Economics and Finance, Micro-enterprises', 
            'Email': ' a.mitra1@lse.ac.uk'}
```

Comment: using your code for the entire list on the website i get the details of 1st 6 but after them i get blank results.

Comment: Some of the pages have missing data, e.g. http://www.gujarat.ngosindia.com/ahmedabad-study-action-group-ahmedabad.html doesn't have "Website". This is to be expected.

Comment: i know some of them miss some data but why is other data which is present not coming ?

Comment: I don't know, you will have to put some `print`s in to find out what you're getting and how to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the contents of the ngos site better, you can give the "split" method a regular expression to split by.
e.g. "[Contact]+[Email]+[telephone number]+[website]+[purpose]+[contact person]

My regular expression could be wrong but this is the direction you should head in.